# How to draw arrows between bubbles

Tags: unity

I have 2 * 3 matrix of bubbles and i want to draw  arrows between those bubbles. it should be done in way as in below Image:-

1 ---->2--->3

What is happening here, When i touch **1 bubble**, start point will set to 1 and if i drag my finger towards 2nd bubble, an arrow that is strechable should draw between these 2 points and if **i continue to drag my finger from 2 bubble to 3rd bubble**,  **another arrow should draw between 2 and 3rd bubble** and continue untill i lift my finger.

Comment: Are you having trouble rendering the lines, rendering the arrow-heads, with recognising touch gestures, or with the geometry involved? Is this a conceptual problem ("I don't understand the problem") or a concrete implementation problem ("I don't know how to solve this problem")?

Comment: Sir,  Actually i m having Collision Detection problem. means when i draw a line between 2 bubbles, it doesn't sense any collision

Comment: What doesn't sense collision? The line, the game or the bubbles? Please edIt the question to clarify.

Comment: Sir, Actually I'm using lineRenderer to draw line between bubbles on touch and i put a box collider to it's head so that when it collide with bubble, it say"Something Touch".   But Nothing is happening here. even though, i can see clearly in Scene View that Line and box collider is clearly collide with another bubble.

Comment: If your problem is that collision events aren't firing, you're much more likely to find an answer by searching for "Unity collision" (eg. http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/search?q=unity+collision ) than something about arrows and bubbles, which doesn't actually describe your issue. For example, one common Unity collision detection issue is that Collision events are only fired when at least one of the GameObjects has a RigidBody (or RigidBody2D) attached. Settings pertaining to "triggers" or "kinematic" can also affect the kinds of collisions that get reported.

Answer (score 0):

This is the pseudo code for what my approach would be. This would go in your update function.

```
If touch location is on a bubble {
    start drawing new arrow
}

If drawing arrow {
    If player stops touching screen {
        stop drawing arrow
    }
    else {
        draw arrow from start touch location to current touch location
        If current touch location is another bubble {
            add completed arrow to draw list
            start drawing new arrow
        }
    }
}
```